# Generate C# class from XML file with mixed type of objects

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have classes like below

```
public abstract class MainDTO
{
   public string Id;
   public string CreatedBy;
}

public class SubDTO : MainDTO
{
   public string SubKey;
}

public class LockDTO : SubDTO
{
   public string LockKey;
}
```

I need to create a function that returns `List<MainDTO>` . My xml file is like below.

```
<MainDTOList>  
  <SubDTO>
    <Id>ABC</Id>
    <CreatedBy>XXX</CreatedBy>
    <SubKey>123045</SubKey>
  </SubDTO>
  <LockDTO>
    <Id>GERTE</Id>
    <CreatedBy>VGINA</CreatedBy>
    <SubKey>123045</SubKey>
    <LockKey>L123045</SubKey>
  </LockDTO>
</MainDTOList>
```

I got the code to read XML file and return collection of objects when all objects are off same type by using XmlSerializer. But in my case they are different. Can you please let me know how to do it.

Comment: pretty much all the same ... have a look at this constructor of XmlSerializer: XmlSerializer(Type, Type[])

Comment: Which serializer?

Comment: If my xml file has all SubDTO only then I will be using XmlSerializer reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<SubDTO>), new XmlRootAttribute("MainDTOList")); but here it is using SubDTO and LockDTO.. so what I must use in new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<xxx>)

Answer (score 0):

The simple way I can think of that you can achieve the above is to look at your XML structure, haven't use this in a bit, so forgive my small assumption mistakes

The idea is to create a class that looks like your XML, if the values only apear once, the use a class that looks like this(as a sample)

```
[XmlRoot("MainDTOList")]
public class SomeClass
{
    [XmlElement("SubDTO")]
    public SubDTO SubDTO{get;set;}

    [XmlElement("SubDTO")]
    public LockDTO LockDTO{get;set;}

    ....

}
```

Then doing a simple [XmlSerializer. Deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization) to deserialize your specific XML